# How do I efficiently make use of chimes as Bard?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen a lot of Bard players going out of lane, leaving their ADR for some time to collect chimes and that makes me think if they (chimes) are really important for Bard, as well as souls for Thresh.

Yes, it upgrades the damage of the meeps, grants EXP and MS and recovers mana too.

But the thing is that the chimes are USUALLY placed far from the lane.

It is risky to wander when the bot lane of the enemy can kill your carry in a jiffy (e.g. Leona, Blitz, Thresh) as well as the fact that the enemy jungler/mid might just run into you. (1 chime = 1 death, really worth)

TL;DR : Is there really an advantage in collecting these 'chimes' than staying in lane? If so, how do I use it (for the MS, EXP and mana) efficiently?

Comment: Have you consider collecting them when your adc is clearly playing safe and cannot be engaged?

Comment: no jutschge answer....weird.... :D

Answer (score 8):

Chimes are quite helpful for Bard. The first 5 are fairly important as they give his meeps a slow (albeit a minor one early on) as well as hitting 25 which gives them AoE damage in a cone. Generally, you should only venture out if the chimes are fairly close or after you have killed an opposing laner. Wards are extremely important to ensure your safety as well as your ADC's. Keep in mind that leaving to collect chimes (while your ADC is safe) benefits both of you. The ADC gets bonus EXP for being solo, while you keep up by getting EXP from you chimes. You can also use this time to gank, something Bard excels at. Still, it comes down to your best judgement. While chimes are important throughout the game, your ADC's life is infinitely more important than missing out on a few chimes. If you aren't 100% confident that your ADC will be fine if you leave to collect a couple chimes, it's usually better to stay. Especially when you are laning against one of the stronger supports in the game such as Leona and Blitz.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you are playing : soloQueue or 5v5 ranked team.

In Solo Queue : try to communicate with your team when youwant to collect chimes, you can collect with them your chimes safely and even you can get some kills and then snowball. If your team don't respond then stay near your adc, it will be better.

In 5v5 ranked team : using a communication tools like skype or Teamspeak 3, make communication more easier. So tell your adc to be safe and roam carefully.

Comment: You are basically saying twice the same thing, once per chat, the 2nd time per skype...

Comment: @dyesdyes basically the same thing . but you know that playing with a team is more easier in communication.
Sadly some players in solo queue don't read the chat or even don't listen even to ping.